# How to end a borrow in a match or if let expression?

Tags: rust

I am using a `HashMap` to store an enum. I'd like to get a value from the `HashMap` and if the value is a specific enum variant, I'd like to insert a modified copy of the value back in the `HashMap`.

The code I came up with looks like this:

```
if let Node::LeafNode(mut leaf_node) = *(self.pages.get(&page).unwrap()) {
   let mut leaf_node = leaf_node.clone();
   // ...
   self.pages.insert(leaf_page,Node::LeafNode(leaf_node)); 
}
```

This does not compile because the borrow of `self.pages` lasts until the end of the `if let`-block and `self.pages.insert` is a mutable borrow.

I have tried to shadow the value of the `HashMap` with a copy of the value, but this does not end the borrow. Usually I would use a `{}` block to limit the borrow, but this seems to be not possible in `match` or `if let`.

What is the idiomatic way to end a borrow so that I can get a new mutable borrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. What you want is called [non-lexical borrows](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811) and it is yet to be implemented in Rust. Meanwhile, you should use [`Entry`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) API to work with maps - in most cases it should be sufficient. In this particular case I'm not sure if entries are applicable, but you can always do something like

```
let mut result = None;
if let Some(&Node::LeafNode(ref leaf_node)) = self.pages.get(&page) {
    let mut leaf_node = leaf_node.clone();
    // ...
    result = Some((leaf_page, leaf_node));
}

if let Some((leaf_page, leaf_node)) = result {
    self.pages.insert(leaf_page, leaf_node);
}
```

It is difficult to make the code above entirely correct given that you didn't provide definitions of `Node` and `self.pages`, but it should be approximately right. Naturally, it would work only if `leaf_page` and `leaf_node` do not contain references to `self.pages` or `self`, otherwise you won't be able to access `self.pages`.

Comment: Do we actually need `Entry` here? I would have thought that `HashMap::get_mut` should be sufficient.

Comment: I'm not sure about entries in this particular case, but they do provide a way to work around some of lexical borrow limitations, that's why I mentioned them.

Comment: And I don't think that `get_mut` is sufficient here because the map itself is modified, not the value.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I thought that the code was just replacing an entry in the map, but it's manipulating an entry at a different key. Sorry.

Comment: Lovely... works. a little unexpected for a rust novice that an Option is needed. Would be a great addition to Rust to have more control ending borrow where needed. I have used a match to simplify it a little, but it's exactly your proposal. thanks!

Comment: Yes, non-lexical borrows will make life much easier. Actually, right now a work is being done to allow them and some other things (namely, implementation of MIR, mid-level intermediate language, and its usage in the compiler), so one can hope that this will be fixed in relatively close time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Vladimir's solution using `match`:

```
let mut result = match self.pages.get(&page) {
    Some(&Node::LeafNode(ref leaf_node)) => Some(leaf_node.clone()),
    _ => None,
};
if let Some(leaf_node) = result {
    // ...
    self.pages.insert(page_number, Node::LeafNode(leaf_node));
};
```