# Dropping partially moved values after the moved values are dropped

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, lifetime

I expect the following code to compile and print `Foo(6)` as the value of `b`, owning the reference to `a` is dropped after the match block.

It seems related to this compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:26:22
   |
13 |     let b = get_foo(&mut a);
   |                          - mutable borrow occurs here
...
26 |     println!("{:?}", a);
   |                      ^ immutable borrow occurs here
27 | }
   | - mutable borrow ends here
```

Dropping the value of `b` doesn't work either, because it is partially moved:

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `b`
  --> src/main.rs:24:10
   |
18 |         Some(value) => *value = y,
   |              ----- value moved here
...
24 |     drop(b);
   |          ^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `(b:std::prelude::v1::Some).0` has type `&mut u32`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Is there a better way to fix this rather than putting lines `let b` and `match b` into an inner block? That just looks weird and ugly.

Shouldn't the compiler understand that the reference is dropped, and be able to compile that code?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(u32);

fn get_foo(bar: &mut Foo) -> Option<&mut u32> {
    Some(&mut bar.0)
}

pub fn test() {
    let mut x = 5;
    let mut y = 6;
    let mut a = Foo(x);

    // {
    
    let b = get_foo(&mut a);

    match b {
        Some(value) => *value = y,
        _ => (),
    }
    
    // }

    //    drop(b);

    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to fix this

Yes, but not in stable Rust. You need *non-lexical lifetimes*:

```
#![feature(nll)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(u32);

fn get_foo(bar: &mut Foo) -> Option<&mut u32> {
    Some(&mut bar.0)
}

pub fn test() {
    let x = 5;
    let y = 6;
    let mut a = Foo(x);

    let b = get_foo(&mut a);

    if let Some(value) = b {
        *value = y;
    }

    println!("{:?}", a);
}

fn main() {}
```

Until then, just use the extra block.

> Dropping the value of b doesn't work either

`drop` has nothing to do with borrows.

See also:

- [Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423)
- [What are the options to end a mutable borrow in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35765440/155423)
- [Why is a borrow still held in the else block of an if let?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30243606/155423)
- [Rust borrow of a HashMap lasts beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423)
- [How to end a borrow in a match or if let expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33495933/155423)
- [Borrow checker and function arguments in Rust, correct or over zealous?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41421107/155423)

Comment: Why would the drop have nothing to do with this? As far as I understand, the compiler is complaining that `b` is/might be holding a reference for `a`. Dropping `b` should take care of that, shouldn't it? NLL takes care of it, I should read up on what it exactly is, but I'm interested in the issue with drop as well.

Comment: @ÁkosVandra if there something you don't understand from the first question I linked to ([Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423)), perhaps adding comments to it would be more appropriate.