# Rust error: borrow occurs after drop a mutable borrow

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow

My test code:

```rust
let mut c = 0;
let mut inc = || { c += 1; c };
drop(inc);
println!("{}", c);
```

rustc says:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `c` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> .\src\closure.rs:20:24
   |
12 |         let mut inc = || { c += 1; c };
   |                       --   ----- previous borrow occurs due to use of `c` in closure
   |                       |
   |                       mutable borrow occurs here
...
20 |         println!("{}", c);
   |                        ^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
21 |     }
   |     - mutable borrow ends here
```

But `inc` is dropped manually before `println!` borrow `c`, isn't it?

So what's the problem with my code? Please help.

Comment: Other related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49499188/3650362, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/3650362, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35765440/3650362

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding of how scopes and lifetimes work is correct. In Rust Edition 2018, they enabled non-lexical lifetimes by default. Prior to that, the lifetime of `inc` would have been to the end of the current lexical scope (i.e. the end of the block) even though its value was moved before that.

If you can use Rust version 1.31 or later, then just specify the edition in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
edition = "2018"
```

If you are using the latest Rust, this will be put there automatically when you create a new crate with `cargo new`.

---

If you are not using Cargo, `rustc` defaults to Edition 2015, so you need to explicitly provide the edition:

```
rustc --edition 2018 main.rs
```

---

If you are using an older nightly build of Rust for some reason, then you can enable non-lexical lifetimes by adding this in your main file:

```
#![feature(nll)]
```

If you are stuck on an older release build, you can usually fix these errors by introducing a shorter scope, using a block like this:

```
let mut c = 0;
{
    let mut inc = || { c += 1; c };
    drop(inc);
    // scope of inc ends here
}
println!("{}", c);
```

Comment: ah sorry about that, I create a canonical question for this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504416/how-do-i-use-a-specific-edition-of-rust/55504418#55504418, hope you don't mind