# Why does the order of declarations have an impact on if compilation succeeds?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I wrote a simple Rust program. Depending on the order of my variable declaration, compilation succeeds or fails.

```
fn main() {
    let my_env: &String;
    let options: Vec<String> = ["a", "b", "c"].iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    my_env = &options[1];
    let _ = my_env;
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `options` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:4:15
  |
4 |     my_env = &options[1];
  |               ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
5 |     let _ = my_env;
6 | }
  | - `options` dropped here while still borrowed
  |
  = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

When I declare `my_env` right after the `options`, the compilation is a success. Is this a Rust feature or a bug?

Comment: Are stuck on Edition 2015 and unable to use Edition 2018 for some reason? Updating to 2018 will solve this problem because of non-lexical lifetimes.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55285018/493729, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/493729

Comment: Any version since 1.31, but you need to enable it in your `Cargo.toml`. See the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55285018/493729

Comment: @x-ray hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504416/how-do-i-use-a-specific-edition-of-rust/55504418#55504418

Comment: Thanks everyone, I thought I needed a new version of Rust, but with the edition="2018" in the toml file, it works.