# How do I use a specific edition of Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know there are currently two editions of Rust (`2015` and `2018`), how can I tell `cargo` and `rustc` which one I want to use?

Comment: See also: [Rust error: borrow occurs after drop a mutable borrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285391/493729)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the following to your `Cargo.toml`, it's documented on the [edition 2018 guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/editions/creating-a-new-project.html):

```
[package]
edition = "2018"
```

---

If you directly use `rustc` you can use `rustc --edition 2018`, it's documented with `rustc --help -v` command.

```
--edition 2015|2018
  Specify which edition of the compiler to use when
  compiling code.
```

Comment: Currently, if `edition` is not set in `Cargo.toml`, it will default to `2015`.